# Checkmate all the kings #1

Tags: chess, board-games

**The purpose of this puzzle is to find the minimum number of moves to checkmate all the kings.**

[image: ![enter image description here]

> **RULES**
>
> - You are playing as White and you can make as many moves as you want before Black's turn.
> - During your moves you can take any black piece except kings.
> - During your moves your king can not be in check position.
> - At the end of your turn all the black kings must be check mate : if Black can make one move that ends with one king being safe, you don't win. Note that this one move can't be a king moving to a threatened position.
> - One piece can be used in multiple checkmates (you don't have to take all the king, just to checkmate them)

**Examples :**

[image]
This is a **valid** ending position because both kings are check mate (A king can not move in a check position to defend another king)

---

[image]
This is **not a valid** ending position because one of the king is not checkmate

---

[image]
This is a **valid** ending : a single piece can checkmate 2 kings

---

*I have tried to make this first puzzle easy to introduce the concept. I will make harder similar puzzles later, feel free to create one yourself too...*

Comment: The two valid/not valid examples where only a part of the board is shown are a bit confusing for me: the "not valid" example seems like not a checkmate only because the leftmost king can move up/down into a non-threatened square. However, without seeing more of the board in the "valid" solution, couldn't either king just move vertically out of the threatened area?

Comment: I'm struggling with your use of the term 'checkmate'. Isn't 'check' when it's threatened, and 'mate' when it cannot make a move to a safe spot? You seem to be using the term 'checkmate' rather then 'check' in your examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got a quick answer but not sure how good it is.

> 1 rook to g6(2 moves), the other rook at a8(1 move)
>  1 knight to d5(2 moves), the other knight to e5(3 moves)
>  total 8 moves

Comment: You are close, but I think your king is in a check position, which is not allowed

Comment: Thanks for the edit... I knew I would make a silly mistake lol...

Answer (score 10):

The answer is indeed

> $8$

as [stack reader discovered](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44389/18250) but here is a visual of the moves:

> [image]

Comment: I have a more optimal solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be done in

> 7 moves: Rxa8 (1 move); N-b4-d3-e5 (3 moves); Rc3-c6 (2 moves); Bc3 (1 move)

If you want a board to play on, you can use [this one on lichess](https://lichess.org/editor/R6r/1pkkkkp1/1pR3p1/3pN3/8/B7/2PPPP2/KN3R2_w_-_-).

Here's the animation:

> [image]

Edit: sadly it does not work. The rook can be taken by the b7 pawn.

Comment: This isn't checkmate sadly. The pawn at B7 can take the rook at C6 putting the king furthest left out of check.

Comment: Good point! What a shame

Comment: Leave it here though, it is still a nice answer. You might want to edit in an explanation of why this doesn't work though