# Checkmate all the kings #2

Tags: lateral-thinking, chess, board-games

Following the rules created by [Lord of dark](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20274/lord-of-dark) in [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44388/checkmate-all-the-kings-1), the idea is to find the minimum number of consecutive white moves to checkmate all the black kings (in this case just 1). You cannot make a move that would put white in check.

[image]

> **RULES**
>
> - You are playing as White and you can make as many moves as you want before Black's turn.
> - During your moves you can take any black piece except kings.
> - During your moves your king can not be in check position.
> - At the end of your turn all the black kings must be check mate : if Black can make one move that ends with one king being safe, you don't win. Note that this one move can't be a king moving to a threatened position.
> - One piece can be used in multiple checkmates (you don't have to take all the king, just to checkmate them)

Comment: Edited my answer (and removed my comment as possibly too spoilery). Nice puzzle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimum possible number of moves is 3:

> xC6 (en passant), c7, c8=N

Comment: OK, that's pretty damn neat.

Comment: Wow, this reminds of classic puzzles by Sam Loyd. great answer :)

Comment: Its worth noting that this first move is only legal if the black pawn got to where it was from a double move rather than two separate moves so I'm not sure if I would consider it valid without that context...

Comment: The normal convention is en passant is illegal UNLESS one can prove the last move must have been c7-c5 (which is clearly wrong here)

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities for a **four-move** mate:

1. > Kd7
2. > Bb8 **OR** B x c5
3. > Kc7
4. > d6

**OR**, if the black pawn has just moved from c7 to c5, a **three-move** mate:

1. > d x c6 (e.p.)
2. > Bb8
3. > c7

Proof that this is optimal:

- > The only white piece which can guard the square a8 is the white-square bishop: obviously the black-square bishop can't, the king can't get close enough, and the pawn can't promote in time.
- > So in order to get a checkmate, the pawn has to move out of the white-square bishop's path.

So **the pawn must move.**

- > The only piece which can place the black king in check is the black-square bishop.

So **the black-square bishop must move.**

- > Regardless of whether it checks from c5 or from b8, the square b8 must be guarded by a friendly piece, and there's nothing which can get there in a single move.

So at least three moves are required. This seems to be the intended solution; but if the black pawn has just moved from c6 instead of from c5, then four moves is optimal; see [this version](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/50118/3) of my answer for a proof.

Comment: Excellent answer. But not quite right!

Comment: @DrXorile You mean it doesn't work or it isn't optimal? (I just edited in a second possibility, btw.)

Comment: It's definitely checkmate! It's just not optimal...

Comment: 3-move answer doesn't work for two reasons; one, it subjects White's king to check from Black's rook following 3rd move, and two, Black king can escape at Kb6.