# Checkmate all the kings #3

Tags: chess, board-games

Following the rules created by [Lord of dark](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20274/lord-of-dark) in [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44388/checkmate-all-the-kings-1), and used [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50117/checkmate-all-the-kings-2) also, the idea is to find the minimum number of consecutive white moves to checkmate all the black kings (in this case 12). You cannot make a move that would put white in check.

[image]

[Here's an interactive board](https://en.lichess.org/editor/kknqqqqq/knPPPPPP/kn6/kkn5/kkn5/kn6/kn3K2/kkn5_w_-_-).

> **RULES**
>
> - You are playing as White and you can make as many moves as you want before Black's turn.
> - During your moves you can take any black piece except kings.
> - During your moves your king can not be in check position.
> - At the end of your turn all the black kings must be check mate : if Black can make one move that ends with one king being safe, you don't win. Note that this one move can't be a king moving to a threatened position.
> - One piece can be used in multiple checkmates (you don't have to take all the king, just to checkmate them)

Comment: How do you get pieces to promote properly with that interactive board? I just tried it, and a promoted pawn can move like a queen but still looks like a pawn.

Comment: It's a bit manual! You just need to drag a queen onto it - it's two interactions. Flexibility vs convenience trade-off...

Comment: I make my animations by opening the link on my phone and taking screen shots there...

Comment: @randal'thor Actually, you can drag the pawn anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thirteen moves:

1. > d x c8
2. > c x d8
3. > h x g8
4. > g x h8
5. > Q x b6
6. > Qc x c5
7. > Q x c4
8. > Q x c1
9. > Qc x b2
10. > Qg2
11. > Qg x b7
12. > Qh3
13. > Qh x b3

Here's an animated GIF of the solution. (Assume all promoted pawns become queens, since I couldn't figure out how to convert them automatically using this particular chess software.)

> [image: Thirteen-move supermate gif]

Comment: This doesn't checkmate all the kings: black can take a queen (any of them) with one of the knights, after which some kings will no longer be in check.

Answer (score 3):

I've done it in 18 moves, one pawn at a time:

Solution:

> [image: Too many Knights]

Moves:

H pawn:

> 1. hxg8=N, Nf6, Ne4, Nc3

G pawn:

> 5. gxf8, Ne6, Nd4, Nc2

C pawn:

> 9. cxd8, Nc6

F pawn:

> 11. Fxe8, Nf6, Nfd5

E pawn:

> 14. e8=N, Nc7

D pawn:

> 16. d8=N, Nde6, Ned4

Comment: This was more what I was aiming for, but the queens do a better job.

Answer (score 3):

Found it in 11, probably the optimal.

> C pawn takes D8 and B6 - 2 moves

.

> D pawn takes C8 and B7 - 2 moves

.

> E pawn takes F8 and C5. Then waits a bit. - 2 moves

.

> F pawn takes G1, C4 and B3. - 3 moves

.

> E pawn now takes C1 and B2. - 2 moves

Comment: Eight knights need to be captured, four pawns need to promote, and only one knight is on the last rank, so you can't do better than 11 moves.